# How to escape $(something) in post-build script in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015, cmd

This is my post-build script that I'm trying to execute:

`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "Compress-Archive -LiteralPath "$(BuiltOuputPath)" -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath "$(BuiltOuputPath)_$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddTHHmm).zip""`

Problem is with this part: `$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddTHHmm)`

Visual Studio replaces it with empty string. How to prevent it? How to escape athat `$` sign and pass it to PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

How about 'whatever'+"_"+$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddTHHmm) ?